# Undefined property error while detecting device in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a page which will detect a device. I using [Detect Device](https://detectdevice.com/) for detecting. But I am getting an error:

[image]

My **Index.php**

```
<?php include 'detect.php'; 

if (Detect::isMobile()) {

}

// Gets the device type ('Computer', 'Phone' or 'Tablet').
echo Detect::deviceType();

// Any phone device
if (Detect::isPhone()) {

}

// Any tablet device.
if (Detect::isTablet()) {

}

// Any computer device (desktops or laptops).
if (Detect::isComputer()) {

}

// Get the IP address of the device.
echo Detect::ip();

// Get the ID address host name of the device.
echo Detect::ipHostname();

// Get the IP address organisation of the device.
echo Detect::ipOrg();

// Get the country the IP address is in (IP address location inaccurate).
// (JS function available which uses GPS)
echo Detect::ipCountry();

// Get the name & version of operating system.
echo Detect::os();

// Get the name & version of browser.
echo Detect::browser();

// Get the brand of device (only works with mobile devices otherwise return null).
echo Detect::brand();

// Check for a specific platform with the help of the magic methods:
if (Detect::isiOS()) {

}

if (Detect::isAndroidOS()) {

}
?>
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to/detect.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<script>
// Get screen width in pixels.
detect.screenWidth();

// Get screen height in pixels.
detect.screenHeight();

// Get viewport (browser window minus any toolbars etc) width in pixels.
detect.viewportWidth();

// Get viewport (browser window minus any toolbars etc) height in pixels.
detect.viewportHeight();

// Get latitude from GPS & update html conent of ID element passed.
// Null, if GPS unavailable.
detect.latitude("latitude");

// Get longitude from GPS & update html conent of ID element passed.
// Null, if GPS unavailable.
detect.longitude("longitude");

// Get address from GPS & update html conent of ID element passed.
// Null, if GPS unavailable.
detect.address("address");
</script>
```

How to solve that error?

Is there any other website which provide function to detect the device?

I am creating a page which will detect a device. I using [Detect Device](https://detectdevice.com/) for detecting. But I am getting an error: [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPvVB.jpg).

Comment: This is not an error. But just a notice !! rest of the code will work perfectly, to suppress this warning check the file detect.php . the line number 248 as seen on the notice..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by your code, but by a bug in the code of the DeviceDetect class. It calls http://ipinfo.io/json. The code assumes that a property called "hostname" always exists, but clearly it's not (based on your error).

Is there a reason why you want to use this DeviceDetect class, and not the http://mobiledetect.net/ variant?

If you want to keep using the DeviceDetect class, you could fix the bug by replacing the lines at 246 with this:

```html
self::$ipInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io' . self::$ipUrl . '/json'));
self::$ipAddress = !empty( self::$ipInfo->ip ) ? self::$ipInfo->ip : '';
self::$ipInfoHostname = !empty( self::$ipInfo->hostname ) ? self::$ipInfo->hostname : '';
self::$ipInfoOrg = !empty( self::$ipInfo->org ) ? self::$ipInfo->org : '';
self::$ipInfoCountry = !empty( self::$ipInfo->country ) ? self::$ipInfo->country : '';
```

Comment: I want this so that I can send emails to the users when they log in, telling them that the user was logged in from computer using chrome .....

Comment: I understand your reason. However in my opinion the DeviceDetect class is not one of the best. It only checks the "happy path" and does no checking if something fails.  Also it does extra HTTP requests to some online services to detect some user information. In my opinion the class from http://mobiledetect.net/ should give you exactly what you need without the extra http calls.

Comment: http://mobiledetect.net just shows you whether it is phone or computer and browser. But I need brand, IP address, location

Comment: Maybe you could use a solution like the maxmind geoip database? See: https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

Comment: How to detect exact location (City) in this?